# ¿Error al ingresar al sistema de acceso se pierde la session y registra datos fallido al ingresar correctamente?

Tags: php, mysqli, session

Cuando el usuario ingresa correctamente con los datos de acceso al sistema este registra en la base datos intentos fallidos en las siguientes tablas.

> **failed_attempt** En esta tabla se contabiliza todo intento fallido tanto como usuario registrado o no registrado todo intento fallido se contabiliza.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **failed_login** En esta tabla se registra intentos fallidos de un usuario que se encuentra registrado en el sistema obteniendo su id -> `id_user`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> No debería registrar en las tablas intentos fallidos, porque el usuario ingreso los datos correctos y accedió al sistema por lo tanto no debería registrar intentos fallidos.

**Los intentos fallidos** se debe registrar cuando se envía datos en blanco, cuando se introduce un usuario que no existe, cuando se introduce un usuario correcto y una contraseña errónea. Todo esto funciona correctamente, ***el error se presenta al acceder correctamente al sistema registra intentos fallidos cuando no debería porque se esta accediendo al sistema correctamente.***

El segundo error se presenta en la `session` al parecer la `session` se está destruyendo o no se está validando correctamente cuando el usuario ingresa los datos correctamente en el login **(login.php)** este es redireccionado a la página principal **(index.php)** todo parece estar perfecto pero no lo es.

> Porque al modificar la **Urls** o al dar clic en el enlace `<a href="login.php">Iniciar Sesión</a>` para acceder a la página **login.php** puedo acceder al `login` y no debería poder ingresar al `login` porque ya he iniciado `sesión` debería redireccionarme nuevamente a la página principal pero no lo hace.

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    /*if(!isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
        header("location:login.php");
    }*/

    function logged_in(){
        return (isset($_SESSION['id_user'])) ? true : false;
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="boton">
    <?php
      if (logged_in() === true){
        echo "Usuario logueado";
      }else{
        echo "usuario no logueao";
       }
    ?>
    </div>
    <div><a href="login.php">iniciar sesion</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $message= $username =  $password = $usernameBD = $passwordDB = NULL;
    $captcha = true;
    //indicador usuario logueado
    $logueado = false;
    //Nro intentos permitidos para IP
    $attemptsIP = 8;
    //Nro intentos permitidos para Usuario
    $attemptsU = 5;

    if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST["vcode"]) && $_POST["vcode"]!=$_SESSION["vcode"]) {
    $captcha = false;
    $message = "Los caracteres escritos no coinciden con la palabra de verificación. Inténtalo de nuevo.";
  }else{
    unset($_SESSION['id_user']);
  }

  $addres = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

  //Conexión -> SQL
  require_once'app/php/config.ini.php';
  //Bloqueamos la ip por un día
  $stmtA = $con->prepare("SELECT attempts FROM failed_attempt WHERE ip=? AND datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND NOW()");

  $stmtA->bind_param("s",$addres);
  $stmtA->execute();
  $stmtA->store_result();

  //Variable para saber si existe registro o no para insert o update.
  $check_result = $stmtA->num_rows;
  if ($stmtA->num_rows===1) { 
  //if ($stmtA->num_rows>0) {
    //Obtenemos datos para comparar intentos y para resetear intentos por su ultimo fecha.
    $stmtA->bind_result($failed_login_attempt);
    $stmtA->fetch();
    $stmtA->close();
  } else {
    $stmtA->close();
    $failed_login_attempt=0;
  }

  if(count($_POST)>0 && $captcha == true) {
    $username = $_POST["username"] ?: '';
    $password = $_POST["password"] ?: '';    

    //Buscar usuario ingresado - INICIO
    $stmtB = $con->prepare("SELECT id_user,username,password,logindatetime, CASE WHEN logindatetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 2 MINUTE ) AND NOW() THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as logueado FROM users where username=? AND active=? LIMIT 1");
    $stmtB->bind_param("si",$username,$active);
    $active=1;
    $stmtB->execute();
    $stmtB->store_result();
    if ($stmtB->num_rows===1) {
        $stmtB->bind_result($id_userBD,$usernameBD,$passwordDB,$logindatetime,$activeBD);
        if ($stmtB->fetch()){
            if (password_verify($password, $passwordDB)) {
                $check_password = true;
            } else {
                $check_password = false;
            }
        } $stmtB->close();
      } else {
        $stmtB->close();
        $check_password = false;
      }

      //Buscar usuario ingresado - FIN

      //registra intentos de login segun IP - INICIO
      //if ($check_username == false) { 

      if($check_result===0){

        //Si es su primer intento fallido, incluimos el primer registro en la BD
        $stmtC = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO failed_attempt (ip,attempts,datetime) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
        $stmtC->bind_param("si",$addres,$attempts);

        $attempts = 1;
        //$datetime = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());
        $stmtC->execute();
        $stmtC->close();

      } else {
        //se actualiza mientras el nro de intentos este abierto, para evitar bug con calculo del dia bloqueado

        if($failed_login_attempt<$attemptsIP){
          $accountant = $failed_login_attempt + 1; 

          $stmtD = $con->prepare("UPDATE failed_attempt SET attempts=?, datetime=NOW() WHERE ip = ?");
          $stmtD->bind_param("is",$accountant,$addres); 

          //$datetime = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());
          $stmtD->execute();
          $stmtD->close();
      }
  }
//}
      //registra intentos de login segun IP - FIN

      //VALIDANDO DOBLE LOGUEO

      if ($username==$usernameBD && $check_password == true && $logindatetime!=NULL && $activeBD==1) {
        $logueado = true;
      } else {
        //registra intentos segun usuario - INICIO
        $attempU = 0;

        if($usernameBD!= null && $usernameBD!=''){

            $id_user = $id_userBD;

            //Sentencia
            $stmtE = $con->prepare("SELECT attempts FROM failed_login WHERE id_user =? AND datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 15 MINUTE ) AND NOW() ");
            $stmtE->bind_param("i",$id_user);
            $stmtE->execute();
            $stmtE->store_result();
            $queryResult = $stmtE->num_rows;

            if ($queryResult===0) {
                $stmtF = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO failed_login (id_user, attempts, ip, datetime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())"); 
                $stmtF->bind_param("iis",$id_user,$attempts,$addres); 
                $attempts=1; 
                $stmtF->execute(); 
                $stmtF->close();
            } else {
                $stmtE->bind_result($attempU_BD);
                $stmtE->fetch();

                $attempU = $attempU_BD+1;

                if ($attempU_BD<$attemptsU) {
                    $stmtG = $con->prepare("UPDATE failed_login SET attempts=?, ip = ?, datetime=NOW() where id_user =?");
                    $stmtG->bind_param("isi",$attempU,$addres,$id_user);
                    $stmtG->execute();
                    $stmtG->close(); 
                }

            } $stmtE->close();
        }
        //registra intentos segun usuario - FIN     
      }  

      //validando Usuario y Contraseña - INICIO

      if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
        $message = "Es necesario introducir un nombre de usuario y contraseña";
      } elseif($failed_login_attempt>=$attemptsIP){
        $message = "'IP' bloqueada por 1 dia";
      } elseif($logueado){
        $message = "'Usuario' ya se encuentra logueado.";
      } elseif($attempU>=$attemptsU){
        $message = "'Usuario' bloqueado por 15 minutos";
      } elseif ($username != $usernameBD ) {
        $message = "El 'Usuario' que has introducido no coincide. ";
      } elseif ($check_password == false) {        
        $message = "Tu 'Contraseña' introducido no coincide. ";
      } else {
        $_SESSION["id_user"] = $id_userBD;
        //$con->query("DELETE FROM failed_attempt WHERE ip = '$addres'");
        //$con->query("DELETE FROM failed_login WHERE id_user ='$id_user'");
      }
      //validando Usuario y Contraseña - FIN
      if(isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
        //echo '<script>window.location="index.php"</script>';
        header('location:index.php');exit;
      }

    }
  }
?>
```

> **Nota:** Al ingresar correctamente al sistema y al acceder al login.php que no debería poder porque ya he iniciado sesión al volver nuevamente a la página principal me muestra el mensaje **no logueado** se está perdiendo o destruyendo la `session` no debería porque no existe aún el código para destruir la `session`

Comment: Me pierdo un poco en la lógica de tu `login.php`. ¿Qué es lo que se ejecuta cuando el usuario se loguea correctamente, el código a partir de `$addres = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`? Luego, dices en comentario del código que usas esto: `if ($stmtA->num_rows===1) {`,  para evaluar si existen registros. Pero esa comparación no es real, ya que  si existe más de una fila que cumple el criterio de la consulta el código correrá como si no existiesen registros.

Comment: Es que lamentablemente no puedo ponerme a analizar un proyecto completo, mucho menos si es algo extenso... podría tardar días, meses, años, comprender la lógica de un programa que no has hecho. Yo te recomiendo que evalúes siempre lo que ocurre en tu código y que vayas depurando, imprimiendo los valores de las variables, etc y que siempre escribas un código controlado, es decir, que nunca asumas que algo va a funcionar por que sí, a veces el código falla por una tontería, porque el programador asume que la variable `$x` debe valer `1` y resulta que por algún motivo `$x` vale `100` o es `null`.

Comment: @A.Cedano No es extenso amigo solo son 3 tablas de la base de datos y el login que es el principal y el index nada más lo puedes ejecutar solo para que puedas comprobar ciertas cosas como por ejemplo el usuario inicia sesión en el sistema porque no se redirecciona a la página principal cuando tratas de ingresar al login.php. No se con exactitud el código no soy el completo autor yo sólo empece el sistema algo simple como este [sistema pero se fue avanzando en el](http://phppot.com/php/show-php-captcha-on-failed-login-attempts/)

Comment: @A.Cedano Exacto amigo estoy de acuerdo en lo que me indicas pero ya he hecho al revés y a derecho todo cambio y prueba y no doy con el error, a simple vista si observamos la `session` del login está correcto ingresas con los datos correctos te redirecciona a la pagina principal ya esta logueado el usuario pero puedo acceder al login cuando no debería porque estoy logueado debería redireccionar nuevamente a la pagina principal porque yo ya he iniciado sesión pero no lo hace?

Comment: Lo que no estas validando es que si el usuario esta logueado, siempre vaya a la pagina principal. Podrias usar algo asi al principio de tu login, `if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {

 header("location: principal.php");

}`

Comment: @LuisFernando Pero al final se encuentra, esto no es lo que validad `if(isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
        //echo '<script>window.location="index.php"</script>';
        header('location:index.php');exit;
      }` que siempre vaya a la pagina principal????

Comment: Pero eso debe de ir al principio, en una condicion if(isset($_SESSION["id_user"])){header('location:index.php');}else{ //ejecuta todo el codigo del login}

Comment: Prueba mi respuesta si no funciona podemos seguir intentando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**login.php**

> No debería registrar en las tablas intentos fallidos, porque el usuario ingreso los datos correctos y accedió al sistema por lo tanto no debería registrar intentos fallidos.

*Culpable:* `if($usernameBD!= null && $usernameBD!=''){`

En esta línea estas comparando si `$usernameBD` es diferente a `NUll`, es decir, si esta iniciado, continua e insértame el fallo.

Ahora piensa cuando inicias sesión y pones correcto tus datos, tu sentencia crea `$usernameBD`, ya que dicha variable se obtiene desde de tu sentencia en caso de que existe el usuario en la comparación de tu `SELECT`, vincula a `$usernameBD` desde la *Base de datos*, entonces siempre te va insertar el fallo si pones correctamente el usuario, porque `$usernameBD` sí existe también en su caso.

Para corregir dicho error, sustituye la línea de arriba por esto:

`if($check_username==true && $check_password == false){`

Es decir, aquí estamos diciendo si el nombre de usuario es correcto pero la contraseña es falsa, insértame el fallo, así evitaras cuando inicias sesión correctamente que no te inserte el fallo.

> **Nota:** `$check_username` No existe aún en tu código, deberás introducirlo de la siguiente forma:

```
if ($stmtB->num_rows===1) {
        $stmtB->bind_result($id_userBD,$usernameBD,$passwordDB,$logindatetime,$activeBD);
        if ($stmtB->fetch()){

          //Usuario existe, creo variable de existencia //////////////////////////
          $check_username = true;
          ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            if (password_verify($password, $passwordDB)) {
                $check_password = true;
            } else {
                $check_password = false;
            }
        } $stmtB->close();
      } else {
        $stmtB->close();
        //Caso falso, Usuario no existe//////////////////////
        $check_username = false;
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $check_password = false;
      }
```

> A tu segundo fallo.

Para evitar el doble login, no veo en tu código que creas la sentencia donde actualizas la fecha de inicio sesión en *login.php*.

Prueba a ver en añadir lo siguiente a tu código a ver si te funciona así y te manda mensaje de ya se ha iniciado sesión:

```
  //validando Usuario y Contraseña - FIN
  if(isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {

    //Vamos a probar añadir un datetime al usuario cuando inicia sesión, para asi saber si esta iniciado o no, sino sera dificil de saber si alguien esta iniciado sesión :).

    //Actualizamos el logindatetime cuando usuario inicia sesión.
    $stmtU = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET logindatetime = NOW() WHERE id_user=?");
    $stmtU->bind_param("i",$id_userBD);
    $stmtU->execute();
    $stmtU->close();

    echo '<script>window.location="index.php"</script>';        
  }
```

Inicie sesión desde dos navegadores diferentes para hacer la prueba, y en el segundo me muestro el mensaje de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice la prueba en `localhost`, con tu `index.php` tal cual, sin modificarla.

### Respuesta a tu comentario: (failed_attempt)

Tu constructor `if($check_result===0){(toda su información)}` debe ir dentro de este nuevo que voy a dejar en el ejemplo de abajo `if ($check_username == false OR $check_password==false) {`, es decir, si el usuario es falso o la contraseña es falso, ingresa un intento en `failed_attemp`

```
//Buscar usuario ingresado - FIN

//registra intentos de login segun IP - INICIO
if ($check_username == false OR $check_password==false) { 

    if($check_result===0){

          //Si es su primer intento fallido, incluimos el primer registro en la BD
          $stmtC = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO failed_attempt (ip,attempts,datetime) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
          $stmtC->bind_param("si",$addres,$attempts);

          $attempts = 1;
          //$datetime = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());
          $stmtC->execute();
          $stmtC->close();

   } else {
          //se actualiza mientras el nro de intentos este abierto, para evitar bug con calculo del dia bloqueado

          if($failed_login_attempt<$attemptsIP){
            $accountant = $failed_login_attempt + 1; 

            $stmtD = $con->prepare("UPDATE failed_attempt SET attempts=?, datetime=NOW() WHERE ip = ?");
            $stmtD->bind_param("is",$accountant,$addres); 

            //$datetime = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());
            $stmtD->execute();
            $stmtD->close();
          }
   }
}
//registra intentos de login segun IP - FIN
```

Comment: Se ha solucionado el intento fallido al ingresar correctamente ya no registra en la tabla `failed_login` pero si registra en `failed_attempt` y no debería tampoco registrar intento fallido en `failed_attempt` porque al igual se esta ingresando correctamente al sistema.

Comment: @J.Mick te he actualizado mi respuesta, te he dejado al final la respuesta para solucionar el problema de `failed_attempt`. Te había enviado por el chat el código completo. Ya me comentas, saludos amigo.

Comment: Hola @D.Bulten , ha pasado mucho tiempo, y hoy en mi baúl de recuerdos estaba dando uso de este sistema, y no me funciona el registro en la tabla del `logindatetine` has mencionado que no estaba actualizando o registrando en lo que indicas en: `Para evitar el doble login, no veo en tu código que creas la sentencia donde actualizas la fecha de inicio sesión en login.php.`

Comment: Pero ya me olvidé del proceso, donde debo agregar ese código, en que parte puedes decirme por favor :)

Comment: @J.Mick el `datetime` lo debes actualizar gusto antes cuando rediriges en tu *login* `echo '<script>window.location="index.php"</script>';`, es decir, antes de dar acceso al usuario si todo está correcto. En mi respuesta lo puedes ver en la parte *A tu segundo fallo*.

Comment: @J.Mick de hecho aun guardo el ejemplo, y lo he probado y a mí me sigue funcionando y me lanza el mensaje *'Usuario' ya se encuentra logueado.* Si me dejas tu correo te puedo enviar mi ejemplo si deseas. Un saludo.

Comment: @J.Mick ya te lo he enviado a tu correo electrónico mediante *WeTransfer*, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Algo asi:

El html

```
<?php
    session_start();
    /*if(!isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
        header("location:login.php");
    }*/

    function logged_in(){
        if(!isset($_SESSION['id_user'])){
  header("location: login.php");
exit;
}
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="boton">
    <?php
      if (logged_in() === true){
        echo "Usuario logueado";
      }else{
        echo "usuario no logueao";
       }
    ?>
    </div>
    <div><a href="login.php">iniciar sesion</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

El login:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
        //echo '<script>window.location="index.php"</script>';
  header('location:index.php');exit;
}else{
  if (isset($_POST)) {
    $message= $username =  $password = $usernameBD = $passwordDB = NULL;
    $captcha = true;
    //indicador usuario logueado
    $logueado = false;
    //Nro intentos permitidos para IP
    $attemptsIP = 8;
    //Nro intentos permitidos para Usuario
    $attemptsU = 5;

    if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST["vcode"]) && $_POST["vcode"]!=$_SESSION["vcode"]) {
      $captcha = false;
      $message = "Los caracteres escritos no coinciden con la palabra de verificación. Inténtalo de nuevo.";
    }else{
      unset($_SESSION['id_user']);
    }

    $addres = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

  //Conexión -> SQL
    require_once'app/php/config.ini.php';
  //Bloqueamos la ip por un día
    $stmtA = $con->prepare("SELECT attempts FROM failed_attempt WHERE ip=? AND datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND NOW()");

    $stmtA->bind_param("s",$addres);
    $stmtA->execute();
    $stmtA->store_result();

  //Variable para saber si existe registro o no para insert o update.
    $check_result = $stmtA->num_rows;
    if ($stmtA->num_rows===1) { 
  //if ($stmtA->num_rows>0) {
    //Obtenemos datos para comparar intentos y para resetear intentos por su ultimo fecha.
      $stmtA->bind_result($failed_login_attempt);
      $stmtA->fetch();
      $stmtA->close();
    } else {
      $stmtA->close();
      $failed_login_attempt=0;
    }

    if(count($_POST)>0 && $captcha == true) {
      $username = $_POST["username"] ?: '';
      $password = $_POST["password"] ?: '';    

    //Buscar usuario ingresado - INICIO
      $stmtB = $con->prepare("SELECT id_user,username,password,logindatetime, CASE WHEN logindatetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 2 MINUTE ) AND NOW() THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as logueado FROM users where username=? AND active=? LIMIT 1");
      $stmtB->bind_param("si",$username,$active);
      $active=1;
      $stmtB->execute();
      $stmtB->store_result();
      if ($stmtB->num_rows===1) {
        $stmtB->bind_result($id_userBD,$usernameBD,$passwordDB,$logindatetime,$activeBD);
        if ($stmtB->fetch()){
          if (password_verify($password, $passwordDB)) {
            $check_password = true;
          } else {
            $check_password = false;
          }
        } $stmtB->close();
      } else {
        $stmtB->close();
        $check_password = false;
      }

      //Buscar usuario ingresado - FIN

      //registra intentos de login segun IP - INICIO
      //if ($check_username == false) { 

      if($check_result===0){

        //Si es su primer intento fallido, incluimos el primer registro en la BD
        $stmtC = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO failed_attempt (ip,attempts,datetime) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
        $stmtC->bind_param("si",$addres,$attempts);

        $attempts = 1;
        //$datetime = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());
        $stmtC->execute();
        $stmtC->close();

      } else {
        //se actualiza mientras el nro de intentos este abierto, para evitar bug con calculo del dia bloqueado

        if($failed_login_attempt<$attemptsIP){
          $accountant = $failed_login_attempt + 1; 

          $stmtD = $con->prepare("UPDATE failed_attempt SET attempts=?, datetime=NOW() WHERE ip = ?");
          $stmtD->bind_param("is",$accountant,$addres); 

          //$datetime = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());
          $stmtD->execute();
          $stmtD->close();
        }
      }
//}
      //registra intentos de login segun IP - FIN

      //VALIDANDO DOBLE LOGUEO

      if ($username==$usernameBD && $check_password == true && $logindatetime!=NULL && $activeBD==1) {
        $logueado = true;
      } else {
        //registra intentos segun usuario - INICIO
        $attempU = 0;

        if($usernameBD!= null && $usernameBD!=''){

          $id_user = $id_userBD;

            //Sentencia
          $stmtE = $con->prepare("SELECT attempts FROM failed_login WHERE id_user =? AND datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 15 MINUTE ) AND NOW() ");
          $stmtE->bind_param("i",$id_user);
          $stmtE->execute();
          $stmtE->store_result();
          $queryResult = $stmtE->num_rows;

          if ($queryResult===0) {
            $stmtF = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO failed_login (id_user, attempts, ip, datetime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())"); 
            $stmtF->bind_param("iis",$id_user,$attempts,$addres); 
            $attempts=1; 
            $stmtF->execute(); 
            $stmtF->close();
          } else {
            $stmtE->bind_result($attempU_BD);
            $stmtE->fetch();

            $attempU = $attempU_BD+1;

            if ($attempU_BD<$attemptsU) {
              $stmtG = $con->prepare("UPDATE failed_login SET attempts=?, ip = ?, datetime=NOW() where id_user =?");
              $stmtG->bind_param("isi",$attempU,$addres,$id_user);
              $stmtG->execute();
              $stmtG->close(); 
            }

          } $stmtE->close();
        }
        //registra intentos segun usuario - FIN     
      }  

      //validando Usuario y Contraseña - INICIO

      if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
        $message = "Es necesario introducir un nombre de usuario y contraseña";
      } elseif($failed_login_attempt>=$attemptsIP){
        $message = "'IP' bloqueada por 1 dia";
      } elseif($logueado){
        $message = "'Usuario' ya se encuentra logueado.";
      } elseif($attempU>=$attemptsU){
        $message = "'Usuario' bloqueado por 15 minutos";
      } elseif ($username != $usernameBD ) {
        $message = "El 'Usuario' que has introducido no coincide. ";
      } elseif ($check_password == false) {        
        $message = "Tu 'Contraseña' introducido no coincide. ";
      } else {
        $_SESSION["id_user"] = $id_userBD;
        //$con->query("DELETE FROM failed_attempt WHERE ip = '$addres'");
        //$con->query("DELETE FROM failed_login WHERE id_user ='$id_user'");
      }
      //validando Usuario y Contraseña - FIN

    }
  }
}
?>
```