# ¿Error en insertar orden del pedido?

Tags: php, mysqli

Al enviar los datos de completar orden, solo se inserta los datos en la primera tabla `order` pero en la tabla `order_details` no registra datos.

Y es direccionado a `/index.php?a=orderfail`

La estructura de mi tabla es la siguiente:

order

```
id_order  id_product  id_user  status
  1          3         2     complete
```

order_details

```
id_order_product  id_product  quantity  price  id_order
      1               3         1       10.00   1
```

*Mi código: **updateorder.php***

```
session_start();
require "conexion.php";
$formid = isset($_SESSION['formid']) ? $_SESSION['formid'] : "";
if ($formid != $_POST['formid']) {
    echo "E00001 !! ERROR DE SESIÓN REINTENTAR OTRA VEZ.";
} else {
    unset($_SESSION['formid']);
    if ($_POST) {

        $id_product = $_POST['id_product '];
        $id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];

        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO order (`id_product`, `id_user`, `status`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ");
        $stmt->bind_param('iis', $id_product,$id_user,$status);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $order_id = $stmt->insert_id;
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['qty']); $i++) {
                $quantity = $_POST['qty'][$i];
                $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
                $id_product = $_POST['id_product'][$i];
                $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO order_details (`id_product`, `quantity`, `price`, `id_order`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ");
                $stmt->bind_param('iisi', $id_product,$quantity,$price,$order_id);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            unset($_SESSION['cart']);
            unset($_SESSION['qty']);
            header('location:index.php?a=order');
        }else{
            $stmt->close();
            header('location:index.php?a=orderfail');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `fetch`  no funciona en INSERT o UPDATE, es para consultas que devuelven conjuntos de resultados. Si cambias: `if ($stmt->fetch()) {` por esto: **`if ($stmt->affected_rows>0){ //Segundo INSERT`** debería funcionar. Aunque yo establecería más controles dentro del bucle (puede que el código falle, por ejemplo al crear claves duplicadas...).También prepararía la inserción, crearía todos mis insert y haría un sólo execute fuera del bucle. Pero eso es secundario para el problema que nos atañe... aunque no es bueno lanzar un insert dentro de un bucle y que éste se quede a medias por algún fallo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ha funcionado lo que has comentado :) pero me gustaría saber esas buenas practicas que comentas en el comentario, ojala tengas un poco te tiempo... y me lo puedas explicar :) gracias ¡Saludos!

Comment: Oscar me parece que sería mejor plantear en otra pregunta la manera de hacer varias inserciones seguidas usando mysqli. Ese no es el problema que dio origen a esta pregunta. Abordar esto aquí, sería alejarse del problema original.

Comment: A.Cedano perfecto entonces ya mismo planteó una nueva pregunta :)

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya he planteado amigo la siguiente [Pregunta de como hacer varias inserciones seguidas usando mysqli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122257/cómo-hacer-varias-inserciones-seguidas-usando-sentencias-preparadas-mysqli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) no funciona en `INSERT` o `UPDATE`, porque se usa para consultas que devuelven conjuntos de resultados, en combinación con [`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), para obtener resultados de columnas específicas. En pocas palabras, `fetch` es para consultas del tipo `SELECT`, en las cuales puedes seleccionar columnas, vincularlas con `bind_result` y entonces leerlas usando `fetch`.

En `mysqli` el método adecuado para manejar resultados de consultas del tipo `INSERT` o del tipo `UPDATE` es :

> ### `affected_rows`
>
> Devuelve el numero de filas afectadas por la última consulta `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `REPLACE` or `DELETE`.
>
> **Valores devueltos**
>
> Un entero mayor que cero indica el número de filas afectadas o recuperadas. El cero indica que no hay registros en
>   una actualización con una sentencia `UPDATE`, que no hay filas que
>   cumplan la cláusula WHERE de la sentencia o que ninguna consulta ha
>   sido ejecutada todavía. -1 indica que la consulta devolvió un error.
>
> <sub>[`affected_rows` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php)</sub>

Entonces, si cambias:

<s>`if ($stmt->fetch()) {`</s>

Por esto:

```
if ($stmt->affected_rows>0){ 
    //Segundo INSERT
```

De ese modo debería funcionar.

Aunque yo establecería más controles dentro del bucle (puede que el código falle, por ejemplo al crear claves duplicadas...).

También optimizaría el código de la siguiente manera:

1. Fuera del bucle, prepararía la inserción:

   ```
   $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO order_details (`id_product`, `quantity`, `price`, `id_order`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ");
   ```
2. Dentro del bucle construiría todas las inserciones a realizar. Esto se podría hacer de diferentes formas. Si tus tablas están en `InnoDB` lo mejor sería usar transacciones. Si usas PDO esto proceso sería muy simple. Ya he expuesto en otras respuestas que todo lo que tenga que ver con consultas preparadas y varios registros se hace más complicado con `mysqli`. No obstante, es una tecnología que está ahí y hay que buscar formas de hacer las cosas para quienes persisten en usar esta API.
3. Una vez preparada nuestra inserción en masa, por la vía que sea... Fuera del bucle ejecutamos la inserción. ¿Por qué hacerlo así? Porque se hace una sola llamada para ejecutar la inserción, no varias llamadas. No sabemos cuántas filas habrá que insertar dentro del bucle. Pero si son cientos, miles, millones... estaríamos haciendo cientos, miles, millones de `execute`, cuando podemos usar uno solo.
4. En el punto 2 hablé algo de las Transacciones. Por lo general, es recomendable usarlas cuando tratamos de insertar varias filas. Ya que si por ejemplo necesitamos hacer unas inserciones determinadas y sólo se insertan unas filas y otras no, porque el código falló en alguna de las inserciones... vamos a tener una cierta cantidad de filas insertadas y otras no. ¿Cómo vamos a saber las filas que se insertaron y las que no lo hicieron?  La consecuencia es una tabla inconsistente en el sentido de que será una tarea harto difícil determinar exactamente qué inserciones se hicieron. Las transacciones aplican el principio de *todo o nada*. Es decir, si alguna inserción falla, se deshacen las inserciones previas a la misma... y te retorna un mensaje de error por ejemplo indicando que ninguna fila fue insertada por el motivo X.

En fin, son sólo observaciones y quizá sea interesante tratar este tema en una pregunta aparte, para poder tener la opinión de varios expertos de esta excelente comunidad.

Comment: Gracias amigo por la aclaración así los temas son más claros cuando son explicados ojala **PHP** tuviera esa posibilidad de explicar pero su contenido es tan pobre lastimosamente. Pero me queda una duda, es cuando dice que no se utiliza `fetch` en `INSERT` o `UPDATE`, quiero tomar una pregunta que me ha sido interesante es la siguiente [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105066/error-al-ingresar-al-sistema-de-acceso-se-pierde-la-session-y-registra-datos-fa) a pesar que no veo que utiliza un `fetch` en los `insert` o `update`

Comment: pero veo que si lo utilizan el `fetch` en un `else` que está relacionado con los `insert` o `update` pero en resumen el procedimiento que han realizado en esa pregunta es correcta. O no?

Comment: @Oscar en la pregunta que refieres, los statements con los que se utiliza `fetch` son los siguientes: `$stmtA, $stmtB, $stmtE`, si te fijas bien en el código, ninguno de esos statements se usa para consultas `INSERT` o `UPDATE`, sino para consultas `SELECT`. Y además, verás que con cada uno de ellos se hace un `bind_result`. Evidentemente, en `bind_result` tú debes indicar las variables a las que quieres asignar los valores de las columnas del `SELECT`. Lo cual no hace un `INSERT` o un `UPDATE` (no te devuelven valores de columnas)  sino la cantidad de filas que fueron afectadas.

Comment: Ah... Comprendido.