# ¿Cómo hacer varias inserciones seguidas usando sentencias preparadas MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

Obtengo en la página **order.php** la verificación de datos, y en el **updateorder.php** guardo los datos de la compra, corresponde al siguiente código:

```
session_start();
require "conexion.php";
$formid = isset($_SESSION['formid']) ? $_SESSION['formid'] : "";
if ($formid != $_POST['formid']) {
    echo "E00001 !! ERROR DE SESIÓN REINTENTAR OTRA VEZ.";
} else {
    unset($_SESSION['formid']);
    if ($_POST) {

        $id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];

        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO order (`id_user`, `status`) VALUES (?, ?) ");
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $id_user,$status);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->affected_rows>0){
            $order_id = $stmt->insert_id;
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['qty']); $i++) {
                $quantity = $_POST['qty'][$i];
                $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
                $id_product = $_POST['id_product'][$i];
                $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO order_details (`id_product`, `quantity`, `price`, `id_order`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ");
                $stmt->bind_param('iisi', $id_product,$quantity,$price,$order_id);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            unset($_SESSION['cart']);
            unset($_SESSION['qty']);
            header('location:index.php?a=order');
        }else{
            $stmt->close();
            header('location:index.php?a=orderfail');
        }
    }
}
```

Guardo los datos de las compra realizada, lo que es el `id` del usuario, precio del producto con sus respectivos `id` el estado de la compra entre más.

Aunque el código funciona correctamente sin errores...

Me han comentado que es mejor utilizar más controles dentro del `bucle` y que posiblemente ***(puede que el código falle, por ejemplo al crear claves duplicadas...).***

> Cómo otra **nota adicional** se dice que no es bueno lanzar un `insert` dentro de un `bucle` y que éste se quede a medias por algún fallo.

A pesar no existir fallos es preocupante saber que puede existir posibles fallos.

> **Otro punto:** Se recomienda preparar la inserción, creando todos los `insert` y hacer un sólo `execute` fuera del `bucle`.

**Entonces mi pregunta es:**

¿Cómo hacer varias inserciones seguidas usando sentencias preparadas MySQLi de forma correcta?

Comment: Oscar, la solución que voy a proponer sería usar [transacciones](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx). La idea es que, si alguna de las inserciones falla, no se ejecutan ninguna de las inserciones precedentes. Se suele hacer de esa manera cuando se van a insertar varios datos (que es lo que haces dentro de tu bucle). De ese modo, si hay algún fallo no quedan unos datos insertados y otros no. Y eso porque luego sería complicado saber cuáles registros se insertaron y cuáles no. Ahora bien, esto sólo funcionará con tablas que estén en `InnoDB`, si están en `MyISAM`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Bueno amigo lo ideal es como dices ***(que si alguna de las inserciones falla, no se ejecuten ninguna de las inserciones precedentes).*** Las estructuras de mis tablas de datos, o el motor de las base de datos están con  `InnoDB`. Saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para mayor limpieza, te recomendaría usar variables distintas para el primer statement y los subsecuentes. (`$stmt1` y `$stmt2`, les puse)

En segundo lugar, para la inserción dentro del bucle, puedes preparar el statement una vez y sólo ejecutar dentro de éste.

```
$stmt1 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO order (`id_product`, `id_user`, `status`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ");
$stmt1->bind_param('iis', $id_product,$id_user,$status);
$stmt1->execute();
if ($stmt1->affected_rows>0){
    $order_id = $stmt1->insert_id;
    // preparo una sola vez
    $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO order_details (`id_product`, `quantity`, `price`, `id_order`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['qty']); $i++) {
        $quantity = $_POST['qty'][$i];
        $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
        $id_product = $_POST['id_product'][$i];
        $stmt2->bind_param('iisi', $id_product,$quantity,$price,$order_id);
        $stmt2->execute();
    }
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
    unset($_SESSION['qty']);
    header('location:index.php?a=order');
}else{
    $stmt1->close();
    header('location:index.php?a=orderfail');
}
```

También podrías encapsular la inserción del bucle en una transacción

```
if ($stmt1->affected_rows>0){
    $order_id = $stmt1->insert_id;
    // Abres una transacción
    $con->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);
    // preparo una sola vez
    $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO order_details (`id_product`, `quantity`, `price`, `id_order`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['qty']); $i++) {
        $quantity = $_POST['qty'][$i];
        $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
        $id_product = $_POST['id_product'][$i];
        $stmt2->bind_param('iisi', $id_product,$quantity,$price,$order_id);
        $stmt2->execute();
    }
    // Ejecutas todas las inserciones en un commit, si una falla no se producen las demás
    $con->commit();

    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
    unset($_SESSION['qty']);
    header('location:index.php?a=order');
}
```

Ahora bien, en este código no estás capturando excepciones. No sabemos si en caso de falla tus sentencias tiran errores de PHP o excepciones de MySQLI.

tendrías que anteponer

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

al código para asegurar que se tiren excepciones y luego manejarlas poniendo, por ejemplo:

```
$con->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);
try {
    $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO order_details (`id_product`, `quantity`, `price`, `id_order`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['qty']); $i++) {
        $quantity = $_POST['qty'][$i];
        $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
        $id_product = $_POST['id_product'][$i];
        $stmt2->bind_param('iisi', $id_product,$quantity,$price,$order_id);
        $stmt2->execute();
    }
    // Ejecutas todas las inserciones en un commit, si una falla no se producen las demás
    $con->commit();
    header('location:index.php?a=order'); // algo que señale el éxito
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $con->rollback();
    header('location:index.php?a=error'); // algo que señale el error
}
```

También la primera inserción debiera estar envuelta en un bloque try/catch.

Me quedan dos interrogantes. Primero, al principio dices que

```
$id_product = $_POST['id_product '];
```

(sobran espacios, pero supongo que es un error tipográfico). Luego en los inserts anidados pones:

```
$id_product = $_POST['id_product'][$i];
```

Entonces, ¿`$_POST['id_product']` es un escalar o un array?

Segundo, en caso de que el primer insert no entregue filas afectadas, estás haciendo `$stmt->close();` ¿Cuál es el propósito? Ese comando va a cerrar un cursor abierto que no se haya terminado de recorrer, pero después de un `INSERT` está de más. Probablemente querías poner `$con->close()` pero en realidad esto tampoco sería estrictamente necesario por la manera como PHP trabaja con las sesiones a BBDD.

Comment: De esto estaba haciendo pruebas si se estaban recibiendo los datos `$id_product = $_POST['id_product']` me olvide comentar, y de esto `$id_product = $_POST['id_product'][$i];` yo recibo datos de esta manera `<input type="hidden" name="id_product[]" value="<?php echo $id_product; ?>" />` no se si con esto se aclare las interrogantes. Saludos!

Comment: Es que entonces el primer `id_product`  que insertas es un array, eso debiera tirarte un error

Comment: no entiendo a que se refiere, si el primer `id_product` como dije era de prueba es decir no había más que el primer `insert` el resto no había.

Comment: Ya, pero `$_POST['id_product']` no puede contener a la vez un `id` y un array de `ids`. Si es un array de productos, te servirá para insertar en `order_details`, pero no para insertar en `order`. ¿Tal vez no necesitas un `id_product` en la primera tabla?

Comment: @amedadiel tienes toda la razón, es que estaba haciendo pruebas primeramente y deje cosas demás en el, pero ya lo he corregido tomando en cuenta sus comentarios, también he realizado cambios en la pregunta para que se vea mucho mejor... Gracias!!!