# ¿Por qué se pierde la sesión en menos 5 minutos?

Tags: php

Tengo preparada la siguiente función para cuando el usuario este logueado:

```
function logged_in(){
    return (isset($_SESSION['id_user'])) ? true : false;
}
```

Para luego poder usar esa función de manera sencilla en mi página, por ejemplo:

```
if (logged_in() === false){
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
```

O de la siguiente forma:

```
if (logged_in() === true){
    echo $name;
}
```

Y, en mi login, como todo funciona bien, porque accedo a la página al loguearme sin problemas, sin embargo agrego la siguiente línea de código que es familiar al resto de código compartido:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
    if (!filter_var($_SESSION["id_user"] ?: '', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) {
        header('location: index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        session_destroy();
    }
}

/*code ...*/

if(isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
    /*
        acceso correcto!
    */
    header('location: index.php');
    exit;
}
```

Cabe recalcar que tengo iniciado el `session_start();` pero de alguna manera se esta perdiendo la sesión después de que exista inactividad, es aceptable que se cierre sesión cuando cierro el navegador, pero no cuando exista inactividad.

¿Me pueden mencionar cual es el problema? Qué cambios debo emplear o de qué forma puedo crear dichas funciones o comprobaciones de `if (logged_in()` o `function logged_in()` o que pude implicar la perdida de sesión.

> Nota: Estoy usando este sistema de Login [¿Error al ingresar al sistema de acceso se pierde la session y registra datos fallido al ingresar correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105066/error-al-ingresar-al-sistema-de-acceso-se-pierde-la-session-y-registra-datos-fa)

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos el resultado de "echo ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");" despues de haber hecho session_start()? Gracias

Comment: @IbaiA. Esto me imprime `1440` ?

Comment: podrías mencionar por favor el nombre del archivo que contine el código del ultimo algoritmo

Comment: @junior cuál exactamente, agregué el link del sistema que estoy utilizando

Comment: es que en el link mencionan dos archivos login.php y index.php en cual esta `if (isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
    if (!filter_var($_SESSION["id_user"] ?: '', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) {
        header('location: index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        session_destroy();
    }
}`

Comment: porque si llegara estar en index.php se formaria un bucle infinito

Comment: ya que se redireccionaría a si mismo infinitamente con una sola vez que la condición sea verdadera

Comment: @junior no eso solamente está en el login.php solo ahí está expuesto dicho código.

Comment: Cuando dices que se cierra por "inactividad" es por inactividad de cuanto tiempo?

Comment: @Pipe no pasa ni 5 minutos y, se cierra sesión, en cambio si estoy indagando en el sitio la sesión se mantiene.

Comment: y que valor retorna: `ini_get("session.cookie_lifetime")`?

Answer (score 2):

Como dijera Jack, *"Vamos por partes"*:

En `login.php` solo debes permitir acceso a usuarios que no han iniciado sesión, entonces esté código es válido:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
    if(filter_var($_SESSION['id_user'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
        // Ya tiene sesión iniciada, no debe tener acceso al formulario
        header('location: index.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        // La sesión no es válida, está bien eliminar todos los valores guardados
        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

Ahora, para las secciones de tu sitio donde se requiere que exista una sesión activa:

```
if(
    // No existe la variable de sesión
    !isset($_SESSION['id_user'])
    // La sesión no es válida
    || !filter_var($_SESSION['id_user'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)
) {
    // No hay sesión activa, redirigir a página para ingresar
    header('location: login.php');
    exit;
}
```

Si quieres ponerlo en una función, devuelve verdadero si existe la variable de sesión y es válida, de lo contrario, devuelve falso:

```
function loggedIn() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['id_user']) && filter_var($_SESSION['id_user'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
}
```

Solo en `login.php`:

```
if(loggedIn() {
    // Ya tiene sesión iniciada, no debe tener acceso al formulario
    header('location: index.php');
    exit;
}
```

En las secciones de tu sitio donde se requiere haber iniciado sesión:

```
if(!loggedIn() {
    // No hay sesión activa, redirigir a página para ingresar
    header('location: login.php');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

primero que todo la expresión `!filter_var($_SESSION["id_user"] ?: '', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)===false` es una doble negacion por este motivo es lo mismo que decir `filter_var($_SESSION["id_user"] ?: '', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)===true` o `filter_var($_SESSION["id_user"] ?: '', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)`.

para obtener las variables de sesión desde otro archivo tienes que volver a abrir la sesión además debe ser por el mismo puerto ya sea que hagas un petición por Ajax o desde la misma petición del navegador.

te muestro como puedes hacer un inicio de sesión utilizando el archivo index desde el cual te logueas para luego verificar las credenciales y redireccionar hacia el home

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="frm" action="control.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user" required/>
    <input type="text" name="pass" required/>
    <button>Ingresar</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**control.php**

```
<?php
$user=isset($_POST['user']) ? Htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['user'])):null;
$pass=isset($_POST['pass']) ? Htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['pass'])):null;
insuser($user,$pass);

function insuser($user,$pass){

    if($usu=="test" && $pas==1234){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["usu"]=$usu;
        $_SESSION["autenti"]='*S¡?ds!%%&{]`';
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='home.php';  </script>";
    }else
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='index.php';</script>";

}
?>
```

**seguridad.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$autenti=isset($_SESSION["autenti"]) ? $_SESSION["autenti"]:NULL;//esta es una varible que lleno cundo se inicie la sesion
$salir=isset($_GET["s"]) ? $_GET["s"]:NULL;// esta la utilizo para cerrar la session por meteodo get
if($autenti!='*S¡?ds!%%&{]`' || $salir=='off'){// *S¡?ds!%%&{]` es una clave que me invente
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php include('seguridad.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>...
```

esto me permite rechazar el ingreso al home si aun no se ha iniciado sesión en el index

Comment: amigo ya tengo un sistema de inicio de sesión, necesito detectar cuál me está ocasionando el problema, ya me has indicado uno, entonces como quedaría mi `if` y, mi `fuction`